# Retrieve data from database after OneToMany Unidirectional Realtion

Tags: java, database, hibernate

So i got this project where i m storing a **"Categorie"** class in data base with onetomany relationship with **"SousCategorie"** class which works fine and it creates a table named **"categorie_sous_categories"**

when i tired to retrieve the data from **categorie_sous_categories** table an error occured that this class is mapped which hibernate had created the table bu i didin't declare the class in my program 
my program structure:
[image]
the exception log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Categorie_sous_categories is not mapped [select categorie_matricule from categorie_sous_categories]
```

the code i try to run:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().
                configure().buildSessionFactory();


        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<String> categorieList = session.createQuery("select categorie_matricule from categorie_sous_categories").list();
        for (String produit:categorieList){
            System.out.println(produit);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

the table i try to retrive data from:
[image]

my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DevIT</property> <!-- BD Mane -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> <!-- DB Driver -->
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property> <!-- DB User -->
        <property name="connection.password">test123</property> <!-- DB Password -->

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> <!-- DB Dialect -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->

        <property name="show_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="CoreApp.Categorie"/>
        <mapping class="CoreApp.SousCategorie"/>
        <mapping class="CoreApp.Produit"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: why don't you try `select categorie_matricule from Categorie`, it will return the same result.

Comment: exception is self explanatory, table `categorie_sous_categories` is not mapped with any *Entity/Class* , it's a mapping table. And it shouldn't be fetched directly, any query you want to run on this table, can be changed - where mapped classes `Categorie  and SousCategorie ` are used.

Comment: you mean when i use both table cat and soucat it will ferch the data from the table where i've got the relation between em ?

Comment: Same data (`categorie_matricule` in `Categorie` and `souscategorylist_souscatmat` in `SousCategorie`)  exist in `Categorie and SousCategorie` , `categorie_sous_categories` is only the mapping, Hibernate will use this mapping table when you get `Categorie` object o get all corresponding `SousCategorie`

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmm i got it thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `select categorie_matricule from Categorie`, it will return the expected result.
Also, exception is self explanatory, table `categorie_sous_categories` is not mapped with any Entity/Class , it's a mapping table. And it shouldn't be fetched directly, any query you want to run on this table, can be changed - where original classes `Categorie and SousCategorie` are being used.